# What is the best way to update an Entity whitout form, FosRest

Tags: rest, api, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm currently build an API with FosRestBundle. I search how can i make a reusable and optimize service for update my entities.

For now, in my controller i get two entites with paramConverter :

```
    /**
 * @Rest\Put("/enseignes/{enseigne_id}",
 *     requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 *@ParamConverter("enseigne", options={"id":"enseigne_id"})
 *@ParamConverter("enseigneUpdate",
 *                converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 *
 * @Rest\View()
 */
public function updateEnseigneAction(Enseigne $enseigne,Enseigne $enseigneUpdate, ConstraintViolationList $violations)
{
    if (count($violations)){
        return $this->view($violations,Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }


    $mapData = $this->get('app.mapdata');
    $mapData->mapDataOnEntity($enseigneUpdate,$enseigne);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->flush();


    return $enseigne;

}
```

So, one entity currently in my bdd with id parameter (and check if the id exist ), and another one who is validate with the converter of fosRest. GOOD

My service look like :

```
  class MapData {

private $propertyMetadata;
private $serializer;


function __construct(MetadataFactory $metadataFactory,Serializer $serializer)
{
    $this->propertyMetadata = $metadataFactory;
    $this->serializer = $serializer;
}


public function mapDataOnEntity($entityUpdate, $targetEntity)
{
    if (get_class($entityUpdate) != get_class($targetEntity)){
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('Entity doesnt match');
    }



    $this->fillProperties($targetEntity,$entityUpdate );
}

/**
 *
 * @param object $targetEntity
 * @param object $entityUpdate
 */
protected function fillProperties($targetEntity, $entityUpdate)
{

    $propertyAccessor = new PropertyAccessor();


    $reflectorTargetEntity = new \ReflectionClass($entityUpdate);

  //        dump($classAnnotaions);die();

  //        Recupere les propriétés de targetEntity
       $properties = $reflectorTargetEntity->getProperties();

  //        dump($properties);die();

    foreach ($properties as $property){
        if ($property->getName() != 'id'){
            $newValue = $propertyAccessor->getValue($entityUpdate,$property->getName());
            $propertyAccessor->setValue($targetEntity,$property->getName(),$newValue);
        }




     }
 }


}
```

First : 
In the properties of my class i have the properties of relation with other entities and i don't want it !

Second:
How i can use this code for manage the PATCH too ? And what do you think about this solution ?

Comment: You should use the form ... It come with so many benefits, validation, binding your model with the request in a clean and evolutive way. Moreover there is simple way to handle PATCH/PUT with forms.
Why have you to go in a generic way like in your example ?

Comment: To be honest, for my last API i use the form and i didn't have a problem. But i'm student and my teacher tell me to don't use it and take advantage of FosRest bundle and the body converter. Also, in a tutorial of OC, same speech, they say don't use the form allow to write less code, so less bug possibility. For cread read and delete it's prettry with the body converter, but there aren't a lot of resources for the update and it's why i search the better and optimize solution.

Comment: I can't help you with the body converter of fos rest. I know that I can handle many cases with forms, but you are using a third library so you have to deal with it :)